# MouseInfo.getPointerInfo() - how to get cursor view

Tags: java, cursor, awt

With `MouseInfo.getPointerInfo()` there is a way to get mouse x,y position which are outer the Java app... And it is fine

But what about the mouse cursor view itself? I mean is there a way to know is the current cursor has a look like DEFAULT or HAND or POINTER or ...? Can it be done with pure Java?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

[Cursor.getDefaultCursor.getType()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Cursor.html#getType%28%29)

Comment: That will return the cursor type that Java will use by default, not the current cursors shape/type, which (I'm guessing) is what the OP is after